# Working with census WMS raster in QGIS

Tags: raster, census

I established a connection to the WMS service of the german census . Displayed correctly.
I've tried to extract values from the specific raster, e.g. population, to polygons like in the picture below.

[image]

I've tried all relevant SAGA VECTOR <-> Raster Tools as shown in the picture below.

[image]

All attempts conclude into an error where it says:

> Grid statistics for polygons:could not initialize data object.

It implies that the tools cant evaluate the data in the raster.

How do I do this working with (german) census raster data?

I am using QGIS 3.10.4.

Comment: The WMS probably does not have the original data in it anyway, instead it is probably classified into a rendered image. To do analysis you usually have to download the data not an image, typically from a WCS for raster or WFS for vector. The capabilities xml should tell you if you can query or download.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. The word "Abfrageformate" means queries. I figured since it only says "esri" something that only ArcGIS queries work on the data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue with finding the original data as WCS service. Sharing it here:

https://monitor.ioer.de/?raeumliche_gliederung=raster&opacity=0.8&zoom=8&lat=51.48822432632349&lng=11.93115234375&glaettung=0&ind=B00DG&baselayer=topplus&time=2011&raumgl=krs&klassenanzahl=7&klassifizierung=haeufigkeit&darstellung=auto&ags_array=&rasterweite=0&